# Issue downloading agent.jar for Jenkins Node setup

Tags: jenkins

I have installed Jenkins v2.448 in Linux server. I am trying to configure Nodes in the Jenkins.
But when I try to download the agent.jar in the slave machine I am getting ERROR : 403 FORBIDDEN. Can someone please help to resolve this problem.
--> wget http://localhost:8080/dpdc/jnlpJars/agent.jar
--2024-03-20 17:04:53--  http://localhost:8080/dpdc/jnlpJars/agent.jar
Connecting to localhost:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2024-03-20 17:04:53 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

I checked all permission and looks okay.